# Elasticsearch : Error in creating replicas in 2 node cluster

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Trying to create index replicas for a 2 node cluster but I'm receiving error when executing the below command to create the replicas in a RHEL environment.

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/*/_settings -H "Content-Type: application/json"" -d "{  "index" : {  "number_of_replicas" : 1}}"

Error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@3c1b6749; line: 1, column: 5]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@3c1b6749; line: 1, column: 5]"},"status":500}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using a double quote to enclose your query that contains double quotes. Use a single quote instead for your `-d` parameter:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/*/_settings -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "index" : { "number_of_replicas" : 1}}'
```

Comment: Thanks Val. I'm able to create the replicas.